# Data Model in android application

Tags: android, pojo

Normally when we fetch data as json format then using POJO class is common format to get and set data via adapters i think. But if i wanna store that data using local DB and only fetch data over network when anything is updated, is that a good approach ?

Comment: any better approach ?

Comment: Not really. You are already on a right track.

Comment: @waqaslam thnx very much